# wordpress navigation for mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a little difficulty with a navigation bar on a wordpress site that I am working on. It displays as it should on a pc but on a mobile it will only display a bar. If I click on the bar, nothing happens.

My HTML is as follows

```
 <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'Mandurah' ); ?></button>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
```

My CSS that I can see calling it is

```
 /* Small menu. */
.menu-toggle,
.main-navigation.toggled ul {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-navigation ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I am very new to responsive design and am sure I am just missing something elementary. This particular site is using a mixture of bootstrap and underscores. Hope you can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your css code with the following code and test it.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .main-navigation ul {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I replaced the code, it removed my main menu even in the desktop view and replaced it with a button. Perhaps if I provide the link for you to see what I am doing wrong mandurahblindcleaning.com

Comment: @Joey I have checked your website and found that you have not included "bootstrap.min.js" so please include it first then apply the above mention css.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. Point to take away is that when working with Bootstrap mobile menus ALWAYS to include the bootstrap.min.js file. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joey If you find this answer helpful then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace your css code with the following code and test it.

`@media only screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-navigation ul {
        display: block;
    }`

Comment: Thanks Rizwan. Weblineindia showed me my rookie error of forgetting to add in the bootstrap.min.js which seems to have sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear only a bar because you set display: none to button :

```
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

From what i see , you are trying to display a menu when you click on the bar ?

Comment: Thanks Marius. Weblineindia showed me my rookie error of forgetting to add in the bootstrap.min.js which seems to have sorted it out.